# Would you explain php code

Tags: php

```
function getParent(&$categories, $category){
    foreach ($categories as &$cat){
        if($category->parentId==$cat[0]->id){
            $cat["subCategories"][$category->id] = array($category,"subCategories"=>array());
            return $cat;
        }
        else if(isset($cat["subCategories"])){
            $this->getParent($cat["subCategories"], $category);
        }
    }
}
```

The $categories(its a chanined list,contain one self id and a foreign id) is a list and $category is one element of the categories.
I don't know what does mean this line `$category->parentId==$cat[0]->id`
why is [0]?And why is constantly 0?Would you explain the whole code?

Comment: What is `$categories`? It's probably an array of arrays.

Comment: Post an example output from `var_dump($categories)`, but copied from the browser page source rather than as rendered by the browser, so linebreaks are left intact.

Comment: looks simple, need way more context to actually know what it is doing.

Comment: `$category` is apparently an object, `$categories` is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: My guess is that $category is a result set which could contain multiple records, but is only returning a single record in this case.

Comment: and what does $cat[0] mean?Why is allways [0]?
I know its the first element of the categories

Comment: I see that this line 
$this->getParent($cat["subCategories"], $category);
is a recursive command.So the whole code must give back the ParentId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if is checking to see if the current category Id is the same as the parent id and then returns an array otherwise it runs though again looking for the next parent.

```
$category->parentId == $cat[0]->id
```

the [0] is constant as it refers to the first item it the array, so rather than knowing the array key this is short hand.

An array in php can have a key $cat['current_id'] and if this was the first key it would also be $cat[0] giving same result.

```
$array = Array('current_id' => 55, 'title' => 'first one');

echo $array['current_id'];

echo $array[0];

if ($array['current_id'] == $array[0]){ echo 'Same'; } else { echo 'Not Same'; }
if ($array['current_id'] == $array[1]){ echo 'Same'; } else { echo 'Not Same'; }
```

All arrays start at 0 for a keys 0,1,2,3...

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-99

http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html

Comment: thank you so much for the very well explained answer.
"current category Id is the same as the parent id"- Do you mean if the current element contain the same id-s?
Because i see in the database that on the top level(whic has no parrent) the parent id is 0

Comment: Yes, they would have the same value in them. Parent ID 0 is usually used for the top category in the tree or root one, so it will have no parent. As a key and value are usually not the same but can be.

Comment: i also see in the database the first column is the id int that case why is $cat[0]->id used insted of just $cat[0]?

Comment: $cat[0]->id indicates its an array item but the item is an object, so you use -> if it was an array off array you would see $cat[0]['id'] using the key instead.